# terratest fails in gitlab ci

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, gitlab-ci, terratest

I am writing a gitlab-ci stage to run terratest tests for my terraform and I get and error when is authenticating to AWS.

I have correctly set as env variables for the pipeline AWS credentials and the tests are successfully running locally.

my stage is:

```
terratest:
  stage: Test and Lint
  image:
    name: "hashicorp/terraform:1.0.5"
    entrypoint:
      - "/usr/bin/env"
      - "PATH=/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
  needs:
    - Package-lambda
  script:
    - go mod init $(basename $PWD)
    - go mod tidy
    - go test ./test/ -v -timeout 30m

  rules:
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME =~ /^(master|production)$/ || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^(master|production)$/'
```

and the error message is:

```
with module.image-lambda-s3-trg.provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"],
TestTerraformFirst 2022-08-10T14:17:13Z logger.go:66: │   on .terraform/modules/image-lambda-s3-trg/image-lambda-s3-trg/main.tf line 2, in provider "aws":
TestTerraformFirst 2022-08-10T14:17:13Z logger.go:66: │    2: provider "aws" {
TestTerraformFirst 2022-08-10T14:17:13Z logger.go:66: │ 
TestTerraformFirst 2022-08-10T14:17:13Z logger.go:66: ╵
TestTerraformFirst 2022-08-10T14:17:13Z retry.go:99: Returning due to fatal error: FatalError{Underlying: error while running command: exit status 1; ╷
│ Error: error configuring Terraform AWS Provider: no valid credential sources for Terraform AWS Provider found.
```

I wonder if the problem can be causes by the fact that I am using a module in my terraform and I just wrote a simple tests to check if the outputs a correct.

any clue on how to debug/solve this?

Comment: Have you verified the AWS credentials are valid in the pipeline outside of the `go` execution?

Comment: how do I do that? I just copied the credential that are in my ~/.aws/credentials file.

Comment: locally, if I run `aws sts get-caller-identity` I get verified, and I used the same ones in the CI

Comment: How are you sourcing credentials? Via environment variables or by other means?

Comment: Locally via AWs configure profile and also via aws-vault so environmental variables. On the ci I just set the pipeline variables and set the same keys I use for my user locally